# My microphone does not work with Flash Player in Mozzila while I have a bluetooth speaker plugged in

Tags: firefox, linux-mint, microphone, flash-player, debian-jessie

My operating system is an up to date Linux Mint Debian Edition 2. This is really just Debian Jessie with an additional repository.

I use Flash to broadcast myself. Flash registers my microphones. However, Flash does not pick up any sound in Mozzila's Firefox, if I have connected my Bluetooth speakers.

This issue must be with Flash itself, because it does not replicate itself in Chrome, which has it's own Flash. I tried switching between the two different versions of Flash, namely " flashplugin-nonfree " and " flashplayer-mozilla ", with no success.

How can I get my mic to work in Flash, in Mozzila? How can I even file a bug for this issue, that presents itself without error messages or any piece of code?